# Best practise to give JS its initial dataset on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Imagine a page that shows a newsfeed. As soon as a user request said page, we go to the database (or whatever) and get the newsfeed. After the page is already loaded, we also have new news items added dynamically (through ajax/json). This means we effectively have two mechanisms to build a newsfeed. One with our server side language for the initial page request, and one with Javascript for any new items.

This is hard to maintain (because when something changes, we have to change both the JS mechanism and the Server side mechanism).

What is a good solution for this? And why? I've come up with the following scenarios:

- Giving javascript an intial set, somewhere in the html, and let it build the initial view when document is ready;
- Letting javascript do an ajax request on document ready to get the initial data; or
- Keep it as described above, having a JS version and a SS version.

I'm leaning towards the first scenario, And for that I have a followup question: How do you give JS the dataset? in a hidden div or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing one more AJAX request to get the data isn't really costly and lets you have one simple architecture. This is a big benefit.

But another benefit you seem to forget is that by serving always the same static resources, **you let them be cached**.

It seems to me there's no benefit in integrating data in your initial page, use only one scheme, AJAX, and do an initial request.

Comment: I did completely miss that. Thank you for the insight. Question: Isn't it so that you'll get double the amount of requests then? Which means twice the load for your webserver (apache/nginx/whatevers accepting the requests)?

Comment: @Coo I'm not sure I get your question. But decoupling the requests (a request for the static page and a request for the data depending on your context) usually doesn't really add requests and make them more cachable, especially if you manage to be RESTfull in your data accesses.

Answer (score 0):

Use a separate news provider to be loaded from page providing data as-is. This will keep things simple and make it load very quickly to be available nearly as fast as any embedded but hidden data set.